# Estimando Pi no JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando estimar Pi, porém recebo um `NaN`.

```js
var x = 0
var y = 0
var fora = 0
var dentro = 0
var f = document.querySelector('input#t')
var t = Number(f.value)
var pi = document.querySelector('div#pi')
var atual = 0
var distance = 0

function start() {
  while (atual < t) {
    x = Math.random()
    y = Math.random()
    distance = x ** 2 + y ** 2
    if (distance <= 1) {
      dentro += 1
      atual += 1
    } else {
      fora += 1
      atual += 1

    }
  }
  pi.innerHTML = 4 * dentro / fora
}
```

```html
<h1>Calculador de pi</h1>
<p>Insira um número de tentavicas</p><input type="number" name="t" id="t"><input type="button" value="start" onclick="start()">
<div id="pi">asdas</div>
```

Comment: `4*dentro/fora` se nunca incrementar o valor de "fora" será uma divisão por zero, pq a variável é iniciada assim `var fora = 0`, deveria iniciar com 1, que é um valor "neutro" na divisão

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alguns erros presentes no seu código:

- iniciar a variável `t` fora da função `start`. Nesse caso, a variável será executada quando o HTML for criado, e nessa etapa, o valor da caixa de texto está vazia, fazendo com que `f.value` seja `''` e `Number('')` seja `NaN`.
- dividindo `dentro` por `fora` ao invés de `atual`.

Você pode corrigi-los dessa forma:

```js
var f = document.querySelector('input#t')
var pi = document.querySelector('div#pi')

function start() {
  var x = 0
  var y = 0
  var fora = 0
  var dentro = 0
  var atual = 0
  var distance = 0
  var t = parseInt(f.value)

  while (atual < t) {
    x = Math.random()
    y = Math.random()
    distance = x ** 2 + y ** 2
    if (distance <= 1) {
      dentro += 1
      atual += 1
    } else {
      fora += 1
      atual += 1
    }
  }
  pi.innerHTML = 4 * dentro / atual
}
```

```html
<h1>Calculador de pi</h1>
<p>Insira um número de tentavicas</p><input type="number" name="t" id="t"><input type="button" value="start" onclick="start()">
<div id="pi">asdas</div>
```

Comment: Realmente, eu tinha colocado o valor de F como o input quando na verdade era pra ser o atual
E sobre o valor fora da função realmente era o que estava dando o NaN. Muito obrigado pela ajuda, agora posso continuar os estudos ! (: